# How do I bind nodes to variables in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to find (bind) all nodes along a found path in an XML.
Consider the following XML snippet.

```
<a at="dat1">
    <b at="dat2">
        <c at="dat3">blah</c>
        <c at="dat4">blah</c>
    </b>
    <b at="dat5">
        <c at="dat6">blah</c>
        <c at="dat7">blah</c>
    </b>
</a>
<a at="dat8">
    <b at="dat2">
        <c at="dat4">blah</c>
        <c at="dat9">blah</c>
    </b>
    <b at="dat10">
        <c at="dat9">blah</c>
        <c at="dat4">blah</c>
    </b>
</a>
```

The xpath query /a/b[@at="dat2"]/c[@at="dat4"] will return only two c nodes. However I would like to retrieve all the nodes along the paths (a,b and c) that satisfy the given conditions. In this case I am expecting two triples of a,b,c nodes. The xpath expression could be arbitrarily complex. The xpath engine would have found the triples, but returns only the c nodes.

I can of course write multiple xpath expressions to get each element. But that will require the xpath engine to search multiple times, which is not really necessary as it already found all the bindings in the first search.

How do I achieve this in xpath?  If it is not possible, which XML querying language should I use?

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you atleast googled?

Comment: @Reborn I did google before posting the question but did not find a solution. I realized that the question was not clear enough, hence I edited it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [XPath axis](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) `ancestor-or-self`. It...

> Selects all ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) of the current node and the current node itself

So `/a/b/c/ancestor-or-self::*` will select all three nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Try below XPath

```
/a/descendant-or-self::*
```

It should return you `a` element as well as `b` and `c`

You can use below for case if `a` has more descendants than just `b` and `c`:

```
//a/descendant-or-self::*[name()=('a', 'b', 'c')]
```